# Excel VBA to PPT, Code Randomly Copies Same Chart Over and Over

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Good day all.  I need a pro to tell me what the heck is going on with my code.  A few things you should know that might affect outcomes:

WIN10
Excel 2016
All Charts are 'Pivot Charts' no chart is connected to a pivot table or table, it connects directly to the data model.  (Chart inserted using PP Utilities).

So the code below shows a macro telling Excel to copy a certain array of charts in different sheets, and to paste them in specific slides in PowerPoint.

However, it seems to want to copy the same one over and over.  For example, the 2nd chart in the array....  it will copy 4 times before it gets back on track with the order I'm telling it to.... so it will copy chart "A-02" 4 times (skip the ones it was supposed to copy and paste) then resume.

I've done lots of trial and error.  I've taken chart "A-02" out completely, but then it will just select the next one in line and copy that several times.

I don't understand why this is happening.  I want it to copy each chart 1 time, and paste it to the designated slide once.  What gives?

```
Sub SCOM_Charts()

ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Object 4")).Select
Selection.Verb Verb:=3

If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
DoEvents
End If

Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone

Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim shp As Object
Dim MySlideArray As Variant
Dim MyChartArray As Variant
Dim X As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

On Error Resume Next

Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

Err.Clear

If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "PowerPoint Presentation is not open, action aborted."
Exit Sub
End If

If Err.Number = 429 Then
MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, action aborted."
Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo 0

PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Activate

Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation

MySlideArray = Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)

MyChartArray = Array(Sheet2.ChartObjects("A-01"), Sheet2.ChartObjects("A- 
02"), Sheet2.ChartObjects("A-04"), Sheet2.ChartObjects("A-07"), 
Sheet2.ChartObjects("A-08"), Sheet1.ChartObjects("V-02"), 
Sheet1.ChartObjects("V-01"))

For X = LBound(MySlideArray) To UBound(MySlideArray)
MyChartArray(X).Copy

On Error Resume Next
Set shp = myPresentation.Slides(MySlideArray(X)).Shapes.Paste
Error GoTo 0

With myPresentation.PageSetup
On Error Resume Next
shp.LinkFormat.BreakLink
End With

Next X

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False

ThisWorkbook.Activate
MsgBox "Export to PowerPoint complete. Note: **All slides will be lost when 
this workbook is closed.**"

End Sub
```

Comment: I think that is possibly is this line of code:

    Set shp = myPresentation.Slides(MySlideArray(X)).Shapes.Paste

Comment: No, the `Paste` command pastes whatever is in the clipboard. I've found that sometimes it takes the clipboard longer to copy objects than it takes VBA to try to execute the next statement, so you end up pasting the object which was in the clipboard before the object that you are copying. You can try inserting the one-line statement `DoEvents` between the copy and paste to give the clipboard a chance to catch up.